# How to send two variables with html as a JSON in Django?

Tags: python, json, django

I want to render two different HTML samples and send it back as response to ajax request.

I have something like this in my view:

```
def getClasses(request):
   User = request.user 
   aircomcode = request.POST.get('aircompany_choice', False)

   working_row = Pr_Aircompany.objects.get(user=User, aircomcode=aircomcode)
   economy_classes = working_row.economy_class
   business_classes = working_row.business_class

   economy = render_to_response('dbmanager/classes.html', {"classes": economy_classes}, content_type="text/html")
   business = render_to_response('dbmanager/classes.html', {"classes": business_classes}, content_type="text/html")

   return JsonResponse({"economy": economy, 
                    "business": business})
```

With this I get the error:

django.http.response.HttpResponse object at 0x7f501dc56588 is not JSON serializable"

How can I do my task?

In js when I get the response I would like to insert received HTML into corespoding blocks. Like this:

```
$.ajax({ # ajax-sending user's data to get user's classes
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    data: {"aircompany_choice": aircompany_choice}, # send selected aircompanies for which to retrieving classes required
    headers: {"X-CSRFToken":csrftoken}, # prevent CSRF attack
}).done (result) ->
    add_booking_classes.find(".economy-classes").children(":nth-child(2)").html(result["economy"])
    add_booking_classes.find(".business-classes").children(":nth-child(2)").html(result["business"])
```

Comment: You shouldn't send html in JSON, it is a bad approach ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Django's `render_to_string` :

```
economy = render_to_string('dbmanager/classes.html', {"classes": economy_classes})
business = render_to_string('dbmanager/classes.html', {"classes": business_classes})
```

`render_to_string()` loads a template, renders it and then returns the resulting string. You can then send these  resulting strings as JSON.

Your final code now becomes:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def getClasses(request):
   User = request.user 
   aircomcode = request.POST.get('aircompany_choice', False)

   working_row = Pr_Aircompany.objects.get(user=User, aircomcode=aircomcode)
   economy_classes = working_row.economy_class
   business_classes = working_row.business_class

   economy = render_to_string('dbmanager/classes.html', {"classes": economy_classes})
   business = render_to_string('dbmanager/classes.html', {"classes": business_classes})

   return JsonResponse({"economy": economy, 
                    "business": business})
```

Answer (score 2):

`render_to_response` is, as the name implies, for rendering a response. You don't want to do that; you want to render two templates, and put them into a JSON response. So use `render_to_string`.

Answer (score 0):

You can send one in your context and one as where you want to render.